# transfer information/variables from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the situation I've got:

Main page, here i have 3 choices(links to the same page) witch actually are 3 types of galleries but they are all on the same page.

Gallery page, when the page is opened it loads the 1st gallery ( i load the others and hide the previously viewed from 3 other buttons which correspond to the other galleries , and i do it with javascript )

I don't really have a way of telling what choice has been made,because they all point at the same page. Since i am doing the whole gallery with javascript , is there anyway to link a variable or something from the 1st page to the 2nd ?

Or just a way of knowing what choice has been made ?

Thanks, and ask away if something is not clear enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't quite tell, are you refreshing the page with each gallery? Or just refreshing display yet maintaining the same initial page?

Comment: Hmm as i reviewed my question i had an idea, if i link the javascript from the 2nd page to the 1st page so that the 1st page also uses the 2nd page's javascript , maybe i can do an mouseover/out variable.

Comment: I am looking at the main page , i make a choice , it loads the gallery page , and then with javascript ( no reloading ) i change the galleries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head...

Since no reloading. In that case, if it was me, I would either make a Javascript object that contained information on my gallery that I needed, like so:

```
var global_galleries = [
    {
       "name": "gallery_1",
       "open_state": true
    },
    {
       "name": "gallery_2",
       "open_state": false
    },
     // -- and so on        
];
```

then set this during your 'gallery open' event. It would make a handy way to catch user actions per gallery.

OR you could do something down and dirty to check the .style.display of your galleries themselves.